# Easiest way to export longitude and latitude data stored in a SQLite database to a file so it can be imported to a Google Map API through a website?

Tags: java, xml, android, google-maps

I have created an application that records a series of longitude and latitude values in a SQLite database and display them as a coloured track on a MapActivity.

I now want to be able to export this data somehow (preferably to a file) so a user can upload the values to a website showing a Google Map API.

My question is: what would be the quickest way to export the data (and in what file format: GPX, XML, CSV) to the SD card located on the Android device.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok Just add this class in your Android Project (with your respective modifications)

```
public class DatabaseAssistant
{
    private static final String EXPORT_FILE_NAME = "/sdcard/datanaexport.xml";

    private Context _ctx;
    private SQLiteDatabase _db;
    private Exporter _exporter;

    public DatabaseAssistant( Context ctx, SQLiteDatabase db )
    {
        _ctx = ctx;
        _db = db;

        try
        {
            // create a file on the sdcard to export the
            // database contents to
            File myFile = new File( EXPORT_FILE_NAME );
                        myFile.createNewFile();

                        FileOutputStream fOut =  new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream( fOut );

            _exporter = new Exporter( bos );
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void exportData( )
    {
        log( "Exporting Data" );

        try
        {
            _exporter.startDbExport( _db.getPath() );

            // get the tables out of the given sqlite database
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master";

                    Cursor cur = _db.rawQuery( sql, new String[0] );
                    Log.d("db", "show tables, cur size " + cur.getCount() );
                    cur.moveToFirst();

                    String tableName;
                    while ( cur.getPosition() < cur.getCount() )
                    {
                        tableName = cur.getString( cur.getColumnIndex( "name" ) );
                        log( "table name " + tableName );

                        // don't process these two tables since they are used
                        // for metadata
                        if ( ! tableName.equals( "android_metadata" ) &&
                        ! tableName.equals( "sqlite_sequence" ) )
                        {
                            exportTable( tableName );
                        }

                        cur.moveToNext();
                    }
                _exporter.endDbExport();
            _exporter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void exportTable( String tableName ) throws IOException
    {
        _exporter.startTable(tableName);

        // get everything from the table
        String sql = "select * from " + tableName;
        Cursor cur = _db.rawQuery( sql, new String[0] );
        int numcols = cur.getColumnCount();

        log( "Start exporting table " + tableName );

//      // logging
//      for( int idx = 0; idx < numcols; idx++ )
//      {
//          log( "column " + cur.getColumnName(idx) );
//      }

        cur.moveToFirst();

        // move through the table, creating rows
        // and adding each column with name and value
        // to the row
        while( cur.getPosition() < cur.getCount() )
        {
            _exporter.startRow();
            String name;
            String val;
            for( int idx = 0; idx < numcols; idx++ )
            {
                name = cur.getColumnName(idx);
                val = cur.getString( idx );
                log( "col '" + name + "' -- val '" + val + "'" );

                _exporter.addColumn( name, val );
            }

            _exporter.endRow();
            cur.moveToNext();
        }

        cur.close();

        _exporter.endTable();
    }

    private void log( String msg )
    {
        Log.d( "DatabaseAssistant", msg );
    }

    class Exporter
    {
        private static final String CLOSING_WITH_TICK = "'>";
        private static final String START_DB = "<export-database name='";
        private static final String END_DB = "</export-database>";
        private static final String START_TABLE = "<table name='";
        private static final String END_TABLE = "</table>";
        private static final String START_ROW = "<row>";
        private static final String END_ROW = "</row>";
        private static final String START_COL = "<col name='";
        private static final String END_COL = "</col>";

        private BufferedOutputStream _bos;

        public Exporter() throws FileNotFoundException
        {
            this( new BufferedOutputStream(
                    _ctx.openFileOutput( EXPORT_FILE_NAME,
                    Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE ) ) );
        }

        public Exporter( BufferedOutputStream bos )
        {
            _bos = bos;
        }

        public void close() throws IOException
        {
            if ( _bos != null )
            {
                _bos.close();
            }
        }

        public void startDbExport( String dbName ) throws IOException
        {
            String stg = START_DB + dbName + CLOSING_WITH_TICK;
            _bos.write( stg.getBytes() );
        }

        public void endDbExport() throws IOException
        {
            _bos.write( END_DB.getBytes() );
        }

        public void startTable( String tableName ) throws IOException
        {
            String stg = START_TABLE + tableName + CLOSING_WITH_TICK;
            _bos.write( stg.getBytes() );
        }

        public void endTable() throws IOException
        {
            _bos.write( END_TABLE.getBytes() );
        }

        public void startRow() throws IOException
        {
            _bos.write( START_ROW.getBytes() );
        }

        public void endRow() throws IOException
        {
            _bos.write( END_ROW.getBytes() );
        }

        public void addColumn( String name, String val ) throws IOException
        {
            String stg = START_COL + name + CLOSING_WITH_TICK + val + END_COL;
            _bos.write( stg.getBytes() );
        }
    }

    class Importer
    {

    }

}
```

instatiate DatabaseAssistant Class

```
DatabaseAssistant DA = new DatabaseAssistant(myContext, mySQLiteDatabase);
```

Do you want export data??? so...

```
DA.exportData();
```

;) hope this help!

Jorgesys

Comment: Jorgsesys, where are you taking the myContext value from in DatabaseAssistant DA = new DatabaseAssistant(myContext, mySQLiteDatabase);

Comment: is the value that you sent from your Activity, you can declare it
as:

private Context myContext;

Comment: @Jorgesys Hi, in line `DatabaseAssistant DA = new DatabaseAssistant(myContext, mySQLiteDatabase);` what is `mySQLiteDatabase);` supposed to be? I tried setting in an object of my DBAdapter class handling all the database access but it din't helped. Also, I tried my database's name that too din't worked. I know its a silly question but am just stuck :|

Answer (score 1):

Hi LordSnoutimus i had a very similar situation so I used this code.

[Export an Android SQLite db to an XML file on the SD Card](http://mgmblog.com/2009/02/06/export-an-android-sqlite-db-to-an-xml-file-on-the-sd-card/)
very useful, just make few changes for your app :)

so lets code it!

Jorgesys

Comment: Hello Jorgesys! The above example is great! but how did you insert it into your existing code? and what do you call to actually run it as it is not an Activity, just a Class.

Thanks!