# Exporting SQLite Table data as XML

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am getting a Null pointer Exception while trying to export my SQLite database's table into an XML file.

**StackTrace:** PasteBin [Link](http://pastebin.com/cZu5gg2B)

--
**Update 2:**
I just don't get it of what is passed in(at time of initializing and calling the exportData Method in Main Activity): `DatabaseAssistant DA = new DatabaseAssistant(myContext, **WHAT_IS_PASSED_HERE?**); DA.exportData();`
--
**Update:**
Lines mentioned where I get NPE are: at `com.astix.reachout.DatabaseAssistant.exportData(DatabaseAssistant.java:72` & `com.astix.reachout.ReachOutMain$9.onClick(ReachOutMain.java:347)`

Which are `_exporter.startDbExport( _db.getPath() );` available inside `DA.exportData()`
 
--
I referred to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2593752/1184579).
My Database Assistant code:

```
public class DatabaseAssistant
{
    public String filNameFullPath;
    public long filNameTS;
    public String EXPORT_FILE_NAME;
    //private static final String EXPORT_FILE_NAME = "/sdcard/datanaexport.xml";

    private Context _ctx;
    private SQLiteDatabase _db;
    private Exporter _exporter;

    public String newfilename(){
        System.out.println("inside newfilename()");

        filNameTS = System.currentTimeMillis();
        filNameFullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        EXPORT_FILE_NAME = filNameFullPath + "/" + filNameTS +".xml";
        System.out.println("new file name: " + EXPORT_FILE_NAME);
        return EXPORT_FILE_NAME;
    }

    public DatabaseAssistant( Context ctx, SQLiteDatabase db )
    {
        _ctx = ctx;
        _db = db;

        newfilename();
        try
        {
            System.out.println("inside try databaseAssitant() -- file name: " + EXPORT_FILE_NAME);
            // create a file on the sdcard to export the
            // database contents to
            File myFile = new File( EXPORT_FILE_NAME );
                        myFile.createNewFile();

                        FileOutputStream fOut =  new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream( fOut );

            _exporter = new Exporter( bos );
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void exportData( )
    {
        log( "Exporting Data" );

        try
        {
            System.out.println("inside try exportData()");
            _exporter.startDbExport( _db.getPath() );

            // get the tables out of the given sqlite database
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master";

                    Cursor cur = _db.rawQuery( sql, new String[0] );
                    Log.d("db", "show tables, cur size " + cur.getCount() );
                    cur.moveToFirst();

                    String tableName;
                    while ( cur.getPosition() < cur.getCount() )
                    {
                        tableName = cur.getString( cur.getColumnIndex( "name" ) );
                        log( "table name " + tableName );

                        // don't process these two tables since they are used
                        // for metadata
                        if ( ! tableName.equals( "android_metadata" ) &&
                        ! tableName.equals( "sqlite_sequence" ) )
                        {
                            exportTable( tableName );
                        }

                        cur.moveToNext();
                    }
                _exporter.endDbExport();
            _exporter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void exportTable( String tableName ) throws IOException
    {
        _exporter.startTable(tableName);

        // get everything from the table
        String sql = "select * from " + tableName;
        Cursor cur = _db.rawQuery( sql, new String[0] );
        int numcols = cur.getColumnCount();

        log( "Start exporting table " + tableName );

//      // logging
//      for( int idx = 0; idx < numcols; idx++ )
//      {
//          log( "column " + cur.getColumnName(idx) );
//      }

        cur.moveToFirst();

        // move through the table, creating rows
        // and adding each column with name and value
        // to the row
        while( cur.getPosition() < cur.getCount() )
        {
            _exporter.startRow();
            String name;
            String val;
            for( int idx = 0; idx < numcols; idx++ )
            {
                name = cur.getColumnName(idx);
                val = cur.getString( idx );
                log( "col '" + name + "' -- val '" + val + "'" );

                _exporter.addColumn( name, val );
            }

            _exporter.endRow();
            cur.moveToNext();
        }

        cur.close();

        _exporter.endTable();
    }

    private void log( String msg )
    {
        Log.d( "DatabaseAssistant", msg );
    }

    class Exporter
    {
        private static final String CLOSING_WITH_TICK = "'>";
        private static final String START_DB = "<export-database name='";
        private static final String END_DB = "</export-database>";
        private static final String START_TABLE = "<table name='";
        private static final String END_TABLE = "</table>";
        private static final String START_ROW = "<row>";
        private static final String END_ROW = "</row>";
        private static final String START_COL = "<col name='";
        private static final String END_COL = "</col>";

        private BufferedOutputStream _bos;

        public Exporter() throws FileNotFoundException
        {
            this( new BufferedOutputStream(
                    _ctx.openFileOutput( EXPORT_FILE_NAME,
                    Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE ) ) );
        }

        public Exporter( BufferedOutputStream bos )
        {
            _bos = bos;
        }

        public void close() throws IOException
        {
            if ( _bos != null )
            {
                _bos.close();
            }
        }

        public void startDbExport( String dbName ) throws IOException
        {
            String stg = START_DB + dbName + CLOSING_WITH_TICK;
            _bos.write( stg.getBytes() );
        }

        public void endDbExport() throws IOException
        {
            _bos.write( END_DB.getBytes() );
        }

        public void startTable( String tableName ) throws IOException
        {
            String stg = START_TABLE + tableName + CLOSING_WITH_TICK;
            _bos.write( stg.getBytes() );
        }

        public void endTable() throws IOException
        {
            _bos.write( END_TABLE.getBytes() );
        }

        public void startRow() throws IOException
        {
            _bos.write( START_ROW.getBytes() );
        }

        public void endRow() throws IOException
        {
            _bos.write( END_ROW.getBytes() );
        }

        public void addColumn( String name, String val ) throws IOException
        {
            String stg = START_COL + name + CLOSING_WITH_TICK + val + END_COL;
            _bos.write( stg.getBytes() );
        }
    }

    class Importer
    {

    }

}
```

And in my main activity(called under onClick of a button):

```
DatabaseAssistant DA = new DatabaseAssistant(myContext, mySQLiteDatabase);
DA.exportData();
```

Here ^ (above is declared as):

```
private Context myContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mySQLiteDatabase;
```

Any suggestion is appreciable..
Thanks

Comment: And which line is the one mentioned in the stack trace?

Comment: @CL. Hi, Thanks for replying. Lines mentioned where I get NPE are: at com.astix.reachout.DatabaseAssistant.exportData(DatabaseAssistant.java:72 & com.astix.reachout.ReachOutMain$9.onClick(ReachOutMain.java:347) Which are `_exporter.startDbExport( _db.getPath() );` available inside `DA.exportData()`

Comment: This information belongs not in a comment but in your question.

Comment: @CL. StackTrace mentions the same. See link in ques descrip. :| Will update my ques with this info. too :) **Updated** Please see my updated ques.

Comment: Which line of those is the 72 line of DatabaseAssistant.java?  I would guess that "myFile" is null.

Comment: @martini Line 72 is: `_exporter.startDbExport( _db.getPath() );`  its in the description under "update".

Comment: @martini and btw myFile is not null as also checked in the stacktrace. I have console printed the value of `EXPORT_FILE_NAME` and its allright.

Comment: So there are 2 suspects: _exporter, _db.  one of them or both are null. Can you check them?

Comment: +1 _db is null (_exporter looks fine) Please see my comment in CL.'s posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Either `_exporter` or `_db` is `null`.

Your constructor initializes both variables, so it is likely that the `mySQLiteDatabase` given to the constructor is already `null`.
(Although you *will* get an invalid `_exporter` if any error happens in the constructor; it is a bad idea to just suppress exceptions and go on as if nothing has happended. This is not the case here because there is not stack trace from that.)

Comment: +1 Yep, _db is null. I suspect that it's due to incorrect parameter which has been passed like: //in my main activity(called under onClick of a button):

`DatabaseAssistant DA = new DatabaseAssistant(myContext, mySQLiteDatabase);
DA.exportData();`

//the above is declared as:

`private Context myContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mySQLiteDatabase;` Actually according to the answer posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2593752/1184579) in line `DatabaseAssistant DA = new DatabaseAssistant(myContext, mySQLiteDatabase);`

Comment: (contd.)what is mySQLiteDatabase); supposed to be? I tried setting in an object of my DBAdapter class handling all the database access but it din't helped. Also, I tried my database's name that too din't worked. I know its a silly question but am just stuck :| (this is the same comment I've posted in that answer too but couldn't get a reply)

Comment: I just don't get it of what is passed in: `DatabaseAssistant DA = new DatabaseAssistant(myContext, **WHAT_IS_PASSED_HERE?**); DA.exportData();`

Comment: See [Using Databases](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db).

Comment: +1 From the above link `You can then get an instance of your SQLiteOpenHelper implementation using the constructor you've defined. To write to and read from the database, call getWritableDatabase() and getReadableDatabase(), respectively. These both return a SQLiteDatabase object that represents the database and provides methods for SQLite operations.`

Comment: (Contd.) I have a `DBAdapter` named class in which I already have `public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
  this.context = ctx;
  DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
 }` umm..so I have to initialize a constructor in my Main activity(from which am calling exportData()) too? Am sorry am new to all this, so can you just point me out to the precise answer as well?

Comment: Why do you have the `DBAdapter`?